# Char array updating

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

I have been working on my hangman program for far to long and cannot figure out why it is not replacing the characters entered with the asterisks.

There are a lot of details I have not added so please do not sit here and judge that. I need someone to tell my why the character the user enters is not replacing the asterisks and If you know what I could do to fix it please tell me.

I'm struggling. I have edited my program to show you where I know the logic error is coming from however I do not know what the error is.

```
  String hiddenWord = wordList[rand];
  char[] asterisks = new char[MAXCHAR];

  hideWord(hiddenWord);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hideWord(hiddenWord)));
  numGuess( hiddenWord,asterisks);

  public static char[] hideWord(String hiddenWord)
  {        
      int wordLength = hiddenWord.length();
      //int length = wordLength * 2;
      char[] asterisks = new char[wordLength];

      for(int i=0; i < wordLength; i++)
      {
          asterisks[i] = '*';
      }
      return asterisks;       
  }

  public static void numGuess(String hiddenWord,char[] asterisks)
  {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      hideWord(hiddenWord);
      int remAttempts = MAXGUESS;

      int i = 0;
      while(i < (hiddenWord.length()-1))
      {
          System.out.println("Enter a letter or 9 to quit");
          char guess = keyboard.next().charAt(i);
          if(asterisks[i] == (hiddenWord.charAt(i)))
          {
              //attemtps == hiddenWord.charAt(i);
              System.out.println("Nice job!");
              remAttempts--;
          }
          i++;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've provided a *lot* of code to work through. It would be a good idea to diagnose the problem as far as you can, and reduce this to a short but complete program which *just* demonstrates the problem. Have you debugged through the code and found the point at which it's not behaving as you expect?

Comment: Yes, It compiles and runs however, when I enter about 2 or 3 characters from my numGuess method it crashes with a string out of bounds error.

Comment: looks like duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411412/array-problems-and-method-trouble?rq=1

Comment: At first glance you call `hideWord(hiddenWord);` without assign its returned value to `asterisks` (which it is not a member variable). But could be something else...

Comment: "It compiles and runs" isn't the same as debugging into it - if it's crashing with an exception, why didn't you mention that before? Please show the full stack trace in your question - and ideally cut this down to a shorter program demonstrating the problem.#

Comment: I have edited my program to show you exactly where the logic error has to be coming from however I do not see it.

Comment: There's a difference between simplifying your problem and just removing some code.  We still would like to be able to figure out the relevant state of the code from a known state, to where you know your error has occurred.  Check out this page on[Simple Self-Contained Correct Examples](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: for your purposes, you can just make a new java program which hardcodes a `String` `hiddenWord` and a `char[]` `asterisks`, copy/paste the `numGuess` method into it, call that method, and then print it's output.

Comment: @JacksonReynalds I've reverted your edit with the new question, since you've already created a new question and got a solution there. If my answer solved this particular question, then feel free to accept it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code (I changed the formatting a bit):

```
while (i < hiddenWord.length() - 1) {
    System.out.println("Enter a letter or 9 to quit");
    char guess = keyboard.next().charAt(i);
    //...
    i++;
}
```

You're asking for a letter, but you really request a String with at least the size + 1 that equals `i`: `keyboard.next().charAt(i);`. Therefore, if you write just a letter, then you'll get an Exception at the second iteration of that loop.

I guess what you meant was: `keyboard.next().charAt(0);`. This will return the first character of the given String.

If this doesn't solve the problem, then provide the whole Stacktrace and mark the line in your code, where the Exception occurs.

Comment: Hey guys I have made some edits and my code is almost working. Could someone take a look at my numGuess method. I have a logic error in comparing the asterisks versus the user letter entered.

Comment: @JacksonReynalds This is a new question. So create a new question, use your new code there and revert your edit of this question.